# jQuery nested :eq selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm new to `jQuery` and I'm trying to select cells in an `table`. My table have, for example 3 cols with 3 cells each.

So I try to select the first cell of the first row, for example, like this:

```
$("#table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)")
```

But doesn't works! What's the right way to do this ?

Comment: That *does* work. Are you sure your problem is not elsewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/3B8cL/

Comment: Is it possible to post the related HTML?

Comment: I can post my code but I believe isn't not so important. My code works well it just doesn't show e.g. this `$("#table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)").html()`

Comment: That selector certainly works, have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/gKWnH/). Are you sure your first row does contain `<td>` elements and not `<th>` elements or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your table has an ID of table? Or should your selector not have the # in it.

If your table does not have an ID of table and you want to select by tagname, the selector of

```
$("table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)");
```

should work. You can also write it in other ways, such as:

```
$("table tr:first td:first");
```

I think the issue *might* be that you've got an erroneous hash in there though ;)

Comment: I don't believe that. I was using the `id` of another table. Goddammit ! Sorry all for such a dumb question !!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use this:

```
$("#table tr:nth-child(0) td:nth-child(0)")
```

i didnt test it though.

*Edit: nth-child is 1-indexed. so it should be nth-child(1).*

Comment: The [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is 1-indexed so this wouldn't work.

Comment: that is true. I just tested the following which worked: 
alert($("#tab tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").html()); (tab is the id of my table)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to make sure it's not working (or is)

`$("#table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)").css('background','red').otherStuff();`

And does your table have the id `table`? Try:

`$("table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)").css('background','red').otherStuff();`